# Python regular expression for retrieving value that is wrapped in quotes

Tags: python, regex

I would like to create a python regular expression that will search through unparsed data that is returned from a webhook:

`{"Opportunity":{"Client Name" :"Mike DevTest","Client Email":"sample@gmail.com","Primary Contact":"Mike DevTest","Event Start Date/Time" : "12/24/2021 4:00 AM","Event End Time":"6:30 PM","Event Location":"Houston","Event Type":"Wedding","State" : "TX","Venue" : "Virtual Chicago","Additional Musicians" : "false","Cocktail Music" : "true","Dinner Music" : "true","Grand Piano Shells" : "false","uplights" : "false","mini piano shells" : "false","projector" : "false","Wedding Ceremony" : "false","Evening Entertainment" : "true","DJ Services" : "true","Type Of Ensemble" : "Dueling Pianos","Primary Owner Email":"sample@gmail.com","Primary Owner Mobile":"(555) 555-555","Salesforce Id":"0068F000002G5quQAC","Added To PIP":"true","Date added to PIP":"3/1/2022","Amount":"1700.00","Performers":"2","Lead Photographer":"true","2nd Photographer":"true","Lead Videographer":"false","2nd Videographer":"false","Client Time Zone":"MT","Studio Time Zone":"ET","Studio Start Time":"12:30 AM","Studio End Time":"1:30 AM","Inbound or Generated":"Generated","Piano Man":"true","Rocket Man":"true","Great Balls of Fire":"true","Main Service Interested In":"Photo"}}`

From the data above, I want it to return the value for the “`Salesforce Id`”, which would be `0068F000002G5quQAC`

Can someone help me with that regular expression?

Comment: That looks like a nested dict. What do you need a regex for?

Comment: If this is a string - looks like JSON. Why not simply use the `json` module to parse it? If you're capturing this via the `requests` module, reponse objects have a `.json()` method you can invoke to parse the response.

Comment: It's for use with Zapier, and is limited in some ways with the amount of code that can be used.  That's why I was looking at a regex solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply access the value by accessing the respective dict keys:

```py
>>> d = {"Opportunity":{"Client Name" :"Mike DevTest","Client Email":"sample@gmail.com","Primary Contact":"Mike DevTest","Event Start Date/Time" : "12/24/2021 4:00 AM","Event End Time":"6:30 PM","Event Location":"Houston","Event Type":"Wedding","State" : "TX","Venue" : "Virtual Chicago","Additional Musicians" : "false","Cocktail Music" : "true","Dinner Music" : "true","Grand Piano Shells" : "false","uplights" : "false","mini piano shells" : "false","projector" : "false","Wedding Ceremony" : "false","Evening Entertainment" : "true","DJ Services" : "true","Type Of Ensemble" : "Dueling Pianos","Primary Owner Email":"sample@gmail.com","Primary Owner Mobile":"(555) 555-555","Salesforce Id":"0068F000002G5quQAC","Added To PIP":"true","Date added to PIP":"3/1/2022","Amount":"1700.00","Performers":"2","Lead Photographer":"true","2nd Photographer":"true","Lead Videographer":"false","2nd Videographer":"false","Client Time Zone":"MT","Studio Time Zone":"ET","Studio Start Time":"12:30 AM","Studio End Time":"1:30 AM","Inbound or Generated":"Generated","Piano Man":"true","Rocket Man":"true","Great Balls of Fire":"true","Main Service Interested In":"Photo"}}
>>> d['Opportunity']['Salesforce Id']
'0068F000002G5quQAC'
```

If this is a string, you can load it using the `json` module before:

```py
>>> s = '{"Opportunity":{"Client Name" :"Mike DevTest","Client Email":"sample@gmail.com","Primary Contact":"Mike DevTest","Event Start Date/Time" : "12/24/2021 4:00 AM","Event End Time":"6:30 PM","Event Location":"Houston","Event Type":"Wedding","State" : "TX","Venue" : "Virtual Chicago","Additional Musicians" : "false","Cocktail Music" : "true","Dinner Music" : "true","Grand Piano Shells" : "false","uplights" : "false","mini piano shells" : "false","projector" : "false","Wedding Ceremony" : "false","Evening Entertainment" : "true","DJ Services" : "true","Type Of Ensemble" : "Dueling Pianos","Primary Owner Email":"sample@gmail.com","Primary Owner Mobile":"(555) 555-555","Salesforce Id":"0068F000002G5quQAC","Added To PIP":"true","Date added to PIP":"3/1/2022","Amount":"1700.00","Performers":"2","Lead Photographer":"true","2nd Photographer":"true","Lead Videographer":"false","2nd Videographer":"false","Client Time Zone":"MT","Studio Time Zone":"ET","Studio Start Time":"12:30 AM","Studio End Time":"1:30 AM","Inbound or Generated":"Generated","Piano Man":"true","Rocket Man":"true","Great Balls of Fire":"true","Main Service Interested In":"Photo"}}'
>>> from json import loads
>>> d = loads(s)
>>>
```